# Android NavigationView set menu from XML programmatically

Tags: android, menu

How do I create Android Navigation View menu from XML programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using design support library you can add Navigation view easily.
Add below code in xml:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_drawer_header"
    app:itemTextColor="#000000"
    app:menu="@menu/global"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

and then create a menu file for navigation

Comment: app:menu="@menu/global" how to  change it programmatically?

Comment: You want to change menu items programatically?

Comment: I want change the title of Navigation Menu Item programmatically!

Comment: You can try some thing like this:         NavigationView navView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navView);
            Menu m = navView.getMenu();
                   MenuItem itemi = m.getItem(m.size()-1);
      item.setTitle("");

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks sooooooooooooooooo much!